# How can I draw several rectangles in a row programmatically?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to put several rectangle i a row. But because I'm new to Android and specially to `Bitmap, Canvas` and so on, I need some help.

**It should look like this, only with rectangles:**

[image]

**I have created one rectangle with this code:**

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg); 
        canvas.drawRect(50, 80, 200, 200, paint); 
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rect);

        ImageView iV = new ImageView(this);
        iV.setImageBitmap(bg);

        ll.addView(iV);
```

But now I dont know how to create more rectangles with different colors in a row. 
I'm really new and sorry for that maybe stupid question but I need help for it.

Can anybody guide me how to do this in the best way?

Comment: I updated [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20611760/1762224). :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here are these lines:

```
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
canvas.drawRect(50, 80, 200, 200, paint);
```

They set the colour and draw a rectangle. You can now repeat these lines to get 2 rectangles:

```
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
canvas.drawRect(50, 80, 200, 200, paint);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#DDDDDD"));
canvas.drawRect(210, 80, 360, 200, paint);
```

Note that I have changed the colour and co-ordinates a little bit. You could continue doing this several times to get all of your rectangles drawn.

Better still use a variable for the x and y coordinates, and use a loop:

```
int left = 50; // initial start position of rectangles (50 pixels from left)
int top = 50; // 50 pixels from the top
int width = 150;
int height = 150;
for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) { // draw 2 rows
    for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++) { // draw 4 columns
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, left+width, top+height, paint);
        left = (left + width + 10); // set new left co-ordinate + 10 pixel gap
        // Do other things here
        // i.e. change colour
    }
    top = top + height + 10; // move to new row by changing the top co-ordinate
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if your rectangle is at (50, 80) pixel co-ordinates and is 200 pixels wide and high, your next one needs to be at (50+200, 80). plus a gap of a few pixels so (50+210, 80). The drawrect method takes these as parameters:  drawRect (float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)

Comment: if i write `canvas2.drawRect(260, 80, 200, 200, paint2);` then I get no gap. just the second rectange gets longer.

Comment: My bad, the drawRect method takes slightly different parameters than I expected. You need to give co-ordinates for all four corners, the last 2 parameters are not lengths. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Im not sure, but I dont think you need to declare new canvas and paint objects, (i.e. canvas2 and paint2) the existing ones should work, so that your drawing on the same canvas. P.s. updated code, to draw 2 rows of 4 rectangles now.

Comment: yes great, thx. And do you know how to set a onclicklistener on each rectangle?

Comment: unfortunately, I dont think this is possible. You can add an event listener to the canvas object and decide if the click co-ordinates fall within the co-ordinates of a particular rectangle, but as the rectangles drawn are not tangible object, they are just drawings on the canvas object, you cannot add event listeners to them, just to the canvas object.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. I tried to self-document my code as mush as possible. This is very dynamic i.e. you can adjust the height, width, xPad, yPad, etc. and the window will compensate.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RectanglesPanel extends JPanel {    
    public static final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
        0xFFFFFF, 0xF67457, 0xFFC238, 0xEFEF38,
        0xBCCACA, 0x75D1E0, 0x84E0C2, 0xC2E749
    };

    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private int width = 80;
    private int height = 50;
    private int rows = 2;
    private int cols = 4;
    private int xPad = 20;
    private int yPad = 30;
    private float strokeWidth = 2.0f;

    int windowWidth = calculateOffset(width, cols, xPad);
    int windowHeight = calculateOffset(height, rows, yPad);

    public RectanglesPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(windowWidth, windowHeight));
    }

    private int calculateOffset(int whole, int partitions, int padding) {
        return (whole * partitions) + (padding * (partitions + 1));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(strokeWidth,
                BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
        ((Graphics2D)g).setStroke(stroke);

        // Fill in background.
        g.setColor(new Color(0xF6F6F6));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                int x = calculateOffset(width, col, xPad);
                int y = calculateOffset(height, row, yPad);
                int color = (row * cols + col) % COLORS.length;

                // Fill in rectangle.
                g.setColor(new Color(COLORS[color]));
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height); 

                // Stroke the border of the rectangle.
                g.setColor(new Color(0xE7E7E7));
                g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new RectanglesPanel();

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you may need to add an offset value for spacing when calculating each consecutive `x` and `y` value.

Comment: It says: The Constructor Color(float,float,float) is undefined.

Comment: [Color\(float r, float g, float b\)](http://tinyurl.com/nuc9pls) - But it does exist...

Comment: Never mind the random colors, I set up an array of colors that reflect the ones in your question.

Answer (score 0):

use for loop keeping the y coordinates constant

```
for(i=0;i<=200;i=i+40)
{
 canvas.drawRect(i,0,i+30,100);
}
```

for next row increase y coordinate by your require amount and repeat the same or use nested for loops

you can set color by

```
myPaint.setColor(color.black);
myPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
canvas.drawRect(0,0,100,100, myPaint);
```